# struct declaration syntax error

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct  stud{

    int roll;
    char name[10];
    double marks;
    }
struct stud stud1={1,"ABC",99.9};
struct stud stud2={2,"xyz",80.0};
int main(){

    cout<<stud1.marks<<"\n"<<endl;
    cout<<stud1.name<<"\n";
    cout<<stud1.roll<<"\n";


     return 0;
}
```

But there are errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: array_structures1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 8/1/2010 9:26:47 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\array_structures1.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  array_structures.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\array_structures1\array_structures1\array_structures.cpp(9): error C2236: unexpected 'struct' 'stud'. Did you forget a ';'?
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.84
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Please help. How can I fix these errors?

Comment: I start to think that all your question should be closed as too localized.

Comment: @Pavel All this guys posts should be be closed as "selfish and lazy", if there were such  a close reason.

Comment: @Neil, yeah, that's what I use "too localized" for.

Comment: guys there are people who help me but somebodys  are trying to decrease my reputation  mark and why i dont understand it was  question  and i have post what was wrong? i have seen many peoples  questions some of them was  very simple but i have never decreased it and why me?

Comment: @davit - I didn't downvote, but I'd imagine that the reason is that the error message tells you exactly what is wrong, and if you'd bothered to read it you wouldn't need to ask the question. I don't even know C++ and I could work out what was wrong in about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know C++, but maybe:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct  stud{

    int roll;
    char name[10];
    double marks;
    }; // notice the semicolon
struct stud stud1={1,"ABC",99.9};
struct stud stud2={2,"xyz",80.0};
int main(){

    cout<<stud1.marks<<"\n"<<endl;
    cout<<stud1.name<<"\n";
    cout<<stud1.roll<<"\n";


     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Please read the error message:

> error C2236: unexpected 'struct' 'stud'. Did you forget a ';'?

You are missing the semicolon at the end of the `struct stud` declaration.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/24/9983984.aspx

Answer (score 1):

"Did you forget a ';'?" Says it all;

After you declare a struct you must put ";".
You can also do this:

```
struct struct_name {
 struct_variables; } new_str;
```

This would create the structure and also create a new variable of that struct type.

So, you could easily have done this:

```
struct  stud{

    int roll;
    char name[10];
    double marks;
    } stud1={1,"ABC",99.9}, stud2={2,"xyz",80.0};
```

And also, after you create a structure, to declare a variable of that structure type you just have to write

---

"stud stud1" instead of "struct stud stud1"

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles perfectly under g++.

But you could try this:

```
struct stud {

    int roll;
    char name[10];
    double marks;
};
```

Comment: Code compiles with <<COMPILER X>> does not, and has never, meant that code is standards compliant.